# Create Simulink block with a number on it

Tags: matlab, simulink

I was wondering how you create the block where there is a number on it.

[image]

The blocks I'm refering to are the ones where there is a 3 or 4. Can't find the right block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Simulink this is a [Gain block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/gain.html) and can be found in the Library browswer under `Simulink -> Commonly Used Blocks`. Or you search for `gain`.